# javascript , php, mysql data displayed into a list

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i am tring to display the data from mysql whith php and java script. I manage to display the data on the page but cant manage to send it to script . below are my files

script1.js

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 done();
});

function done() {
      setTimeout( function() { 
      updates(); 
      done();
      }, 200);
}


function updates() {

  $.getJSON("cocktail.php", function(data){
      $("ul") .empty ();

      $each(data.result, function(){
          $("ul").append("<li>Poza: "+this['poza']+"</li> <li>Nume: "+this['nume']+"</li><li>Compozitie: "+this['compozitie']+"</li><br/>");

  });
   }); 
}
```

cocktail.php

```
<?php include ('includes/header_js.php');?>
<?php include_once ('includes/connection.php');?>

<div class="body_bg">
                        <h2>Arta Cocktail-urilor</h2>


                        <div class="clr"> </div>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM   cocktail";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$result = array ();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($res) )
{

array_push($result, array('poza' => $row[1],
                            'nume' => $row[2],
                            'compozitie' =>$row[3]));
}
echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));

?>

 </div><!--end of body_bg-->

<?php include ('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

connection.php

```
<?php 
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root'. '');
if(!$connection){
die('Nu s-a putut conecta la baza de date.' .mysql_error());    
}
$db_select = mysql_select_db('first_class', $connection);
if(!$db_select){
die('Eroare de conexiune'.mysql_error());   
}

?>
```

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>First Class Cocktail</title>
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css"  type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<table></table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/script1.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="header">




                </div><!--end of logo-->
        <div class="menu">
         <ul>
          <li><a href="index.php" class="active"><span>Acasa </span></a></li>
          <li><a href="galerie.php"><span>Galerie</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="cocktail.php"><span>Cocktail</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="about.php"><span> Despre Noi </span></a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.php"><span> Contact </span></a></li>
        </ul>

        </div><!--end of menu-->
        <div class="clr"></div><!--end of clr-->
```

where do i faild??? Thank you in advance for the time wasted reading this!
Thank you!

Comment: sooo..... `cocktail.php` does display the correct data?  but `script1.js` is unable to get it with `$.getJSON`... is that correct?  are you getting any errors?  is the `updates` function actually being called?  is the data just coming back blank or....?

Comment: What is the value of `data` after the `$.getJSON("cocktail.php", function(data){` line?

Comment: `$each` is a syntax, error, too... should be [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)....

Comment: the page cocktail.php it display the data from mysql but in a raw way: {"result":[{"poza":"\"images\/cocktail\/mojito.jpg\"\/>","nume":"Mojito","compozitie":"15cl rom, gheata, menta"}]}  the script it supposed to arrage it in a list more cleaner

Comment: yes that is what i want to succed.

Comment: that seems fine... answer @JonKoops's question...

Comment: @user2776660 I think the data being returned from `cocktail.php` isn't valid JSON. Could you add the result of `cocktail.php` to your question?

Comment: I'd also appreciate if you post the contents of `includes/header_js.php`

Comment: the resupt is:{"result":[{"poza":"\"images\/cocktail\/mojito.jpg\"\/>","nume":"Mojito","compozitie":"15cl rom, gheata, menta"}]}

Comment: the content is the sheam as header.php

Comment: @user2776660 So there is HTML in the response of `cocktail.php`?

Comment: yes i may say it is html

Comment: @user2776660 Well that's the problem. I'll post an elaborate answer below.

Comment: @user2776660 I've added my answer, please provide feedback there if you're experiencing issues still.

Comment: Thank you so much .... I am still experiencing problems now I see all html not just the line that i used to.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mtuihw0azo3aa8q/what_i_see.png the red sqare was what i used to see.

Answer (score 1):

You're generating a multi-level array:

```
array_push($result, array('poza' => $row[1], etc...);
```

will create an aray like:

```
$result = array(
     0 => array('poza' => ....)
);
```

meaning you have to use

```
      $("ul").append("<li>Poza: "+this[0]['poza']+ etc...);
                                      ^^^---- note this
```

in your JS code.

Your PHP-side code can be tremendously simplified:

```
SELECT poza, nume, compozitie FROM ...

$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $data[] = $row;
};
```

As well, your JS code seems to be assuming there will only ever be ONE row of data coming out of the database, yet your database handling code is set up to handle MULTIPLE rows. Not my place to figure out which one is correct, but you should be aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `cocktail.php` contains HTML whilst the `$.getJSON` function expects JSON (and JSON only). You should also return a valid `Content-Type` header for JSON like `application/json`. In the end your `cocktail.php` would look something like this:

```
<? 

include_once('includes/connection.php');

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$sql = 'SELECT poza, nume, compozitie FROM cocktail';
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$results = array();

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ) {

    $results[] = $row;

}

echo json_encode( array('results' => $results) );

?>
```

On a sidenote, I see you're using the `mysql_...` functions. These functions are deprecated in newer versions of PHP, it's highly recommended to use the newer PDO functions to future-proof your code (for more information look here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

There are also some issues with your JavaScript code.

```
$each(data.result, function(){
```

Should be

```
$.each(data.result, function ( index, value ) {
```

You should also replace

```
this['poza']
```

with

```
value.poza
```

Finally your JavaScript would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var updateList = function () {

        $.getJSON('cocktail.php', function( data ) {

            var list = $('ul');

            list.empty();

            $.each(data.results, function( index, result ) {

                list.append(
                    '<li>Poza: ' + result.poza + '</li>' +
                    '<li>Nume: ' + result.nume + '</li>' +
                    '<li>Compozitie: ' + result.compozitie + '</li>'
                );

            });

        });
    };

    window.setInterval(updateList, 200);

});
```